# StoredProcedureItemReader not able to retry on java.sql.SQLTimeoutException

Tags: spring, spring-batch, batch-processing, spring-retry

I am having difficulty in getting my StoredProcedureItemReader to Retry after it fails due to SQLTimeoutException.
Here is the configuration for my step process:

```
@Bean    
public Step Step() throws Exception {       
            return stepBuilderFactory.get("Step")
                    .<Student, Student>chunk(100)
                    .reader(storedProcItemReader())
                    .processor(studentItemProcessor)
                    .writer(fileItemWriter())
                    .faultTolerant()
                    .retryLimit(5)
                    .retry(QueryTimeoutException.class)
                    .retry(SQLTimeoutException.class)
                    .backOffPolicy(backoffPolicy())
                    .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public RetryableItemReader<Student> storedProcItemReader() throws Exception {
        return studentItemReader.getDataFromDatabase(dataSource);
    }
```

studentItemReader class file:

```
@Component
@StepScope
public class studentItemReader{

    public RetryableItemReader<Student> getDataFromDatabase(DataSource dataSource) {
        
RetryTemplate retryTemplate = RetryTemplate.builder()
                .maxAttempts(5)
                .exponentialBackoff(1000, 2, 20000)
                .retryOn(QueryTimeoutException.class)
                .retryOn(SQLTimeoutException.class)
                .build();

            StoredProcedureItemReader<RegionResponse> reader = new StoredProcedureItemReader<>();
            
            SqlParameter[] parameter = { new SqlParameter("@studentId",
                    java.sql.Types.INTEGER) };
            PreparedStatementSetter statementValues = new PreparedStatementSetter() {
                @Override
                public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
                    ps.setInt(1, parameterValue);
                    }
            };
            reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
            reader.setProcedureName("dbo.StudentReport");
            reader.setParameters(parameter);
            reader.setPreparedStatementSetter(statementValues);
            reader.setRowMapper(new StudentRowMapper());
            reader.setQueryTimeout(1500);
            return new RetryableItemReader<>(reader, retryTemplate);
        }   
    }
}
```

Retry:

```
import org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader;
import org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate;

public class RetryableItemReader<T> implements ItemStreamReader<T> {

    private final StoredProcedureItemReader<T> delegate;
    private final RetryTemplate retryTemplate;

    public RetryableItemReader(StoredProcedureItemReader<T> delegate, RetryTemplate retryTemplate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.retryTemplate = retryTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public T read() throws Exception {
        return retryTemplate.execute(context -> delegate.read());
    }

    @Override
    public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
        delegate.open(executionContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
        delegate.update(executionContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws ItemStreamException {
        delegate.close();
    }
}
```

I am seeing this in the logs where it isn't able to retry:

```
2021-09-09 19:21:10.405 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-4] WARN  c.z.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection:182      - HikariPool-1 - Connection ConnectionID:4 ClientConnectionId: bf81d056-0bc4-4657-b201-bc638d128f13 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(HY008), ErrorCode(0)
java.sql.SQLTimeoutException: The query has timed out.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:226)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.execute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:505)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyCallableStatement.execute(HikariProxyCallableStatement.java)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader.openCursor(StoredProcedureItemReader.java:213)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.doOpen(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:428)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:150)
    at gov.va.med.ccrs.pit.extract.retry.RetryableItemReader.open(RetryableItemReader.java:25)
    at gov.va.med.ccrs.pit.extract.retry.RetryableItemReader$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7ad4b84a.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    at gov.va.med.ccrs.pit.extract.retry.RetryableItemReader$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a742dbe0.open(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:103)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkMonitor.open(ChunkMonitor.java:114)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:103)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:311)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:205)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:138)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2021-09-09 19:21:10.406 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-3] DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate:324      - Retry: count=0
2021-09-09 19:21:10.406 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-3] DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate:324      - Retry: count=0
2021-09-09 19:21:10.408 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-3] DEBUG o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate:324      - Retry: count=0
2021-09-09 19:21:10.522 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] ERROR o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep:237     - Encountered an error executing step slaveStep in job Pit-Extract
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:153)
    at gov.va.med.ccrs.pit.extract.retry.RetryableItemReader.open(RetryableItemReader.java:25)
    at gov.va.med.ccrs.pit.extract.retry.RetryableItemReader$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7ad4b84a.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    at gov.va.med.ccrs.pit.extract.retry.RetryableItemReader$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a742dbe0.open(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:103)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkMonitor.open(ChunkMonitor.java:114)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:103)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:311)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:205)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:138)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.QueryTimeoutException: Executing stored procedure; SQL [{call dbo.StudentReport(?)}]; The query has timed out.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTimeoutException: The query has timed out.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:76)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader.openCursor(StoredProcedureItemReader.java:229)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.doOpen(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:428)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:150)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTimeoutException: The query has timed out.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:226)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.execute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:505)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyCallableStatement.execute(HikariProxyCallableStatement.java)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader.openCursor(StoredProcedureItemReader.java:213)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
2021-09-09 19:21:10.522 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-4] ERROR o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep:237     - Encountered an error executing step slaveStep in job Pit-Extract
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:153)
    at gov.va.med.ccrs.pit.extract.retry.RetryableItemReader.open(RetryableItemReader.java:25)
    at gov.va.med.ccrs.pit.extract.retry.RetryableItemReader$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7ad4b84a.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    at gov.va.med.ccrs.pit.extract.retry.RetryableItemReader$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a742dbe0.open(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:103)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkMonitor.open(ChunkMonitor.java:114)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:103)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:311)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:205)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:138)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.QueryTimeoutException: Executing stored procedure; SQL [{call dbo.StudentReport(?)}]; The query has timed out.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTimeoutException: The query has timed out.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:76)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader.openCursor(StoredProcedureItemReader.java:229)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.doOpen(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:428)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:150)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTimeoutException: The query has timed out.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:226)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.execute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:505)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyCallableStatement.execute(HikariProxyCallableStatement.java)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader.openCursor(StoredProcedureItemReader.java:213)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
2021-09-09 19:21:10.582 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2] WARN  c.z.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection:182      - HikariPool-1 - Connection ConnectionID:5 ClientConnectionId: 161fd25b-5a39-465c-b1a6-8116952b1972 marked as broken because of SQLSTATE(HY008), ErrorCode(0)
java.sql.SQLTimeoutException: The query has timed out.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:226)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.execute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:505)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyCallableStatement.execute(HikariProxyCallableStatement.java)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader.openCursor(StoredProcedureItemReader.java:213)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.doOpen(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:428)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:150)
    at gov.va.med.ccrs.pit.extract.retry.RetryableItemReader.open(RetryableItemReader.java:25)
    at gov.va.med.ccrs.pit.extract.retry.RetryableItemReader$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7ad4b84a.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    at gov.va.med.ccrs.pit.extract.retry.RetryableItemReader$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a742dbe0.open(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:103)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkMonitor.open(ChunkMonitor.java:114)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:103)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:311)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:205)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:138)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2021-09-09 19:21:10.583 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2] ERROR o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep:237     - Encountered an error executing step slaveStep in job Pit-Extract
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:153)
    at gov.va.med.ccrs.pit.extract.retry.RetryableItemReader.open(RetryableItemReader.java:25)
    at gov.va.med.ccrs.pit.extract.retry.RetryableItemReader$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7ad4b84a.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
    at gov.va.med.ccrs.pit.extract.retry.RetryableItemReader$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a742dbe0.open(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:103)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkMonitor.open(ChunkMonitor.java:114)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:103)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:311)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:205)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:138)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:135)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.QueryTimeoutException: Executing stored procedure; SQL [{call dbo.StudentReport(?)}]; The query has timed out.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTimeoutException: The query has timed out.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:76)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader.openCursor(StoredProcedureItemReader.java:229)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractCursorItemReader.doOpen(AbstractCursorItemReader.java:428)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:150)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTimeoutException: The query has timed out.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:226)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.execute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:505)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyCallableStatement.execute(HikariProxyCallableStatement.java)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.StoredProcedureItemReader.openCursor(StoredProcedureItemReader.java:213)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
2021-09-09 19:21:12.888 [custom-executor1] ERROR o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep:237     - Encountered an error executing step masterStep in job Student-Info-Extract
org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Partition handler returned an unsuccessful step
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.PartitionStep.doExecute(PartitionStep.java:112)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:68)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:68)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:137)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:319)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:147)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Please let me what mistake I am doing here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `RetryableItemReader` only retries the `read` operation, but the timeout is happening while initializing the reader, ie in the `open` method. This can be seen here:

```
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:153)
    at gov.va.med.ccrs.pit.extract.retry.RetryableItemReader.open(RetryableItemReader.java:25)
...
```

This method is not retried in your `RetryableItemReader`. You can make it retryable as you did for the `read` method, something like:

```
@Override
public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
    retryTemplate.execute(new RetryCallback<Object, ItemStreamException>() {
        @Override
        public Object doWithRetry(RetryContext retryContext) throws ItemStreamException {
            delegate.open(executionContext);
            return null;
        };
    });
}
```

That said, I would investigate why the timeout is happening as it could happen again down the road when reading actual data (even if this is retried).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply but adding that code to the open method in RetryableItemReader is throwing a compile time error:
 - Cannot infer type argument(s) for <T, E> execute (RetryCallback<T,E>)
 - Cannot return a void result

Comment: I did not compile the code at first, that's why I said "something like". But I hope you understand the cause of your issue and you get the idea of how to fix it. You need to  make the method where the exception is likely to be thrown retryable. I updated the answer with a snippet that should work. Please update it accordingly if needed.